# Is there a way to avoid the first parameter of mongoose.model() altogther?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We want to use camelcase in our MongoDB database collections.

But if we pass the name of our model as the first parameter like this:

```
const CompanyEmployeeModel = mongoose.model("CompanyEmployeeModel", Schema);
```

Mongoose creates a plural collection name as all lowercase in the database.

```
companyemployeemodels
```

In order to avoid this, we pass a third parameter with the exact name of collection name:

```
const CompanyEmployeeModel = mongoose.model("CompanyEmployeeModel", Schema, "companyEmployeeModels");
```

This generally works, but then:

1. the first parameter seems to have no use anymore
2. sometimes when using nodemon while creating an API, and before typing the third parameter, Mongoose will execute the code and create collections in the database named e.g. `companyems` or `companyemployeemos` and once even `s` (!)

**How can we avoid this first parameter altogether so we simply send Schema and collection name so that the code is clearer and Mongoose doesn't create unwanted collections in the database?**

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you generally can't.

1. mongoose needs a way to distinguish different collections from one another in order for the features of mongoose to work properly. For example, you can include a `ref` property in a field of one of your models, which refers to a *collection name*. This way, you can use the `model.populate` function, without the need to express how to populate a certain field. Also note that the first parameters specifies the name of the *model* AND *collection* (just the plural thereof). So renaming by taking the model out might make it clearer.
2. I'm not sure what is going on here. CamelCase has never failed for me so far. For the line above however, in my experience, you can skip the third parameter as mongoose automatically handles collection naming. Perhaps there something else going on with your code someplace else that is causing the faulty collection naming. I don't know.